# what is the difference between turn out and come out

Tags: word-choice, orthography, phrase-meaning

What should be the correct answer for the question below.Please help.

Nobody believed Galileo's theory initially but it -came out- to be right.
(1)worked out
(2)turned out
(3)carried out
(4)no improvment

Comment: You may want to check out [Ell.SE].

Comment: Idiomatically, *turned out* is the only credible alternative here. We'd normally only use *worked out [**all** right]* (and to a lesser extent, *came out*) in contexts where we're talking about a *practical method* that people were initially sceptical of, but which actually produced "right"/good results when used. Not when we mean it was *[subsequently recognised to be] **correct***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [prove out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prove%20out) works as well

Comment: @Lumberjack: *Proved out* [full stop] is okay, *proved (to be) correct* similarly, but would anyone say ? *proved out to be correct*?

Comment: @ Lumberjack: Actually, for OP's context, I think only [but it proved right](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but+it+proved+right%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is acceptable. That's 82 written instances in Google Books, but there are *none at all* for [but it proved **out** right](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but+it+proved+out+right%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @TimLymington not in any dialect I'm familiar with.  Instead (as a native American English speaker) I would say "Nobody believed Galileo's theory initially but it proved out."  Or, perhaps more clear is: "Nobody believed Galileo's theory initially but in time it proved out."

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it was a test question.  I would have abstained from answering had I read the question more closely.  I don't like to help people cheat.

Comment: @Lumberjack: that's a mighty strange dialect you've got there. I would never ever follow the word "proved" with the word "out".

Comment: @Marthaª Merriam Webster doesn't find it so strange: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prove%20out.  I imagine the differences in dialect between New England and Pennsylvania are numerous.

Comment: @Lumberjack: also, just because it's a multiple-choice question doesn't mean the OP is cheating by posting here.

Comment: @Marthaª Cleary, it is an assumption that I am jumping to with little supporting evidence.  What is factual is that OP has a question, and he is looking for the "correct answer."  My offer of "prove out" was of no value, as it was not one of the available choices for a "correct answer."

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by @FumbleFingers in his comment, **turned out** is appropriate, and *came out* is not in the example given.

There is a related meaning for *[come out](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/came-out)* that *seems* as if it might apply

> to yield a satisfactory solution ⇒ *these sums just won't come out*

However, *come out* is usually used to describe the result of an active process, such as the calculation in the example, rather than a more theoretical analysis by Galileo. It is often used to describe recipes or manufacturing operations.

> How did the pie *come out*?

In almost all cases, *turn out* can be used in place of *come out*, but the obverse is not true.

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference in better words than my comment. Yes - it's all about the difference between something being *right/correct* (atemporally, in and of itself), and "the result of an active process" being *[al]right, satisfactory, desirable* in terms of ***outcome***.

Comment: No offense, but I don't think OP cares about learning.  He just wants help cheating on his test.

Comment: @Lumberjack: how is learning the answer different from 'cheating'?

Comment: @TimLymington Fairly straight forward: a cheater wants to know which answer is correct, not *why* it is correct.